# Does rabbitmq support binding a single queue to multi exchanges?

Tags: rabbitmq

I know that an exchange can bind multi queues in rabbitmq, does it support binding a single queue to multi exchanges?

Comment: yes , can bind a queue to multiple exchange . what would you do that? please give me a little more description

Answer (score 16):

**YES**, it can.

A queue can have any number of bindings to different exchanges, even multiple bindings to the same exchange with different parameters.

You do this by invoking the `bind` method multiple times, see:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.bind

Comment: Keep in mind that when you bind a single queue to multiple exchanges it will be the responsibility of consumer app to choose the right handler when a message is consumed by the app. Depending on the framework, this may require additional work: e.g. in "Masstransit" (.net) this feature is built-in, while in "streadway/amqp" (golang) subscribers of the same queue will be handled in round-robin.